# Does partition filter order has significant performance impact on spark read

Tags: apache-spark

Example :  table XXXX is partition by column1 and column2

```
           reading table XXXX by where clause Column1 and column2
           option 1: select xxxx where column1 ="" and column2 =""
           option 2: select xxxx where column2 ="" and column1 =""
          
   does option 1 and option 2 has different read performance because of filter order and table partitionBy column1 and column2?

i have checked DAG for both case which is having partitionFilter in filescan.

question is 
option1 : where(column1 ="" and column2 ="")
option 2: where(column2 ="" and column1 ="" ) 
does it have differenet read performance beacuse of table patition by column1, column2?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say it should make not a difference as ultimately the mapping (ie the total amount of processing time **added** to fetch the first partition and then the second) will happen the same either way. Basically ...

t(column1) + t(column2) = t(column2) + t(column1)

but this is a tricky question that should be tested with different cardinalities and formats for each column.